# Refactoring Grails templates to expect maps instead of lists

Tags: grails

Grails 2.4.4 here. I currently have a GSP that displays a list of `Widget` objects like so:

```
// The Widget domain object
@Canonical
class Widget {
    String title
    String history
}

// The controller
class WidgetController {
    def widgetService   // Grails Service provided below

    def index() {
        def widgetType = params.widgetType
        def model = widgetService.getAllWidgetsByType(widgetType)

        render(view: 'index', model: model)
    }
}

// WidgetService
class WidgetService {
    def widgetDataService // Omitting for brevity; makes a call to a DB

    def getAllWidgetsByType(widgetType) {
        def model = [:]
        def widgetList = widgetDataService.getWidgets(widgetType)

        model.put('widgetList': widgetList)
        model.put('foo', 'baz')
        model.put('fizz', 'buzz')

        model
    }
}

// grails-app/views/widget/index.gsp
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Here are the widgets:</h2>
            <g:render model="[providedWidgetList:widgetList]" template="/shared/widgetBlock"></g:render>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

// grails-app/views/shared/_widgetBlock.gsp
<g:each var="widget" in="${providedWidgetList}">
    <div id="widgetBlock">
        <h3>${widget.title}</h3>
        <span>${widget.history}</span>
    </div>
</g:each>
```

So, to recap:

1. `WidgetService` pulls back a `List<Widget>` from a DB and plops that into a `model` map (along with) some other stuff
2. `WidgetController` feeds this model to a `widget/index.gsp`
3. `widget/index.gsp` renders a `shared/widgetBlock` template that generates a `widgetBlock` div tag for each widget in the returned List

So, if there are 3 widgets returned by the DB, the resultant HTML might look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Here are the widgets:</h2>
            <div id="widgetBlock">
                <h3>Hello There, Little Widget!</h3>
                <span>What a nice little widget.</span>
            </div>
            <div id="widgetBlock">
                <h3>My Fair Widget</h3>
                <span>The best there ever was.</span>
            </div>
            <div id="widgetBlock">
                <h3>A Time of Dogs!</h3>
                <span>It was a time of tradition. It was a time of Dogs.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I now need to add a new property to the `Widget`, a `favoriteFood` property, so that now `Widget` looks like:

```
@Canonical
class Widget {
    String title
    String history
    String favoriteFood // values might be 'Pizza', 'French Fries' or 'Ice Cream'
}
```

And now, in the UI, I need the widget list visually-grouped by `favoriteFood`, so that widgets who share the same favorite food appear in their own section like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- omitted for brevity -->
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <h2>Here are the widgets:</h2>

            <h3>Pizza</h3>
            <hr/>
            <div id="widgetBlock">
                <h3>Hello There, Little Widget!</h3>
                <span>What a nice little widget.</span>
            </div>
            <div id="widgetBlock">
                <h3>My Fair Widget</h3>
                <span>The best there ever was.</span>
            </div>

            <h3>Ice Cream</h3>
            <hr/>
            <div id="widgetBlock">
                <h3>A Time of Dogs!</h3>
                <span>It was a time of tradition. It was a time of Dogs.</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So in the above example, the first two widgets both have `favoriteFood = 'Pizza'` and the last widget alone loves `Ice Cream`.

To accomplish this, I need to group all the widgets (returned from the DB) according to `favoriteFood`, so something like this:

```
def widgetsByFavoriteFood = widgetList.groupBy { widget -> widget.favoriteFood}
```

However because of how the service returns a `model` map, and how the `index.gsp` invokes and renders the template, and because the template is expecting a list (not a map), I'm just not seeing where I would make these changes.

**Very important:** This is a gross simplification of my *actual* Grails app. There are several things I cannot change without enormous refactoring (which I really don't want to have to do):

- I really can't change the fact that the `WidgetService` returns a `model` map
- I really can't change the fact that the `widget/index.gsp` invokes the `_widgetBlock`

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the change right in the GSP. I consider your case *UI logic*, so it makes sense to put it in the GSP.

*Oops, that was an opinion ;)*

```
<g:each var="entry" in="${widgetList.groupBy { widget -> widget.favoriteFood } }">
    <!-- entry.key is the favorite food, 
    and entry.value is the list of widgets grouped under 
    the favorite food -->
</g:each>
```

Iterating over a `Map`, which is what `groupBy()` returns, produces `Map.Entry`s.

### Tip:

You can build your model much more succinctly like this:

```
[widgetList: widgetList, foo: 'baz', fizz: 'buzz']
```

Answer (score 0):

So you get a grossly simplified answer...  :)

The service returns a map -- still a map, just the inner details of the widgetList elements are different (rather than a list of individual items, have it return a list of lists of items. Maybe extract the favorite food into a parent element.

```
[
    widgetList:[
        [
            favoriteFood:'Pizza',
            widgets:[
                [
                    title: 'title1',
                    history: 'blah'
                ]
            ]
        ],
        [
            favoriteFood:'Eggses',
            widgets:[]
        ]
    ],
    foo: 'baz',
    fizz: 'buzz'
]
```

Widget block has to change no? Not sure what your groupBy yields exactly but,

```
g:each var foodGroup in widgetList
    output the foodGroup stuff: h3, hr
    g:each var widget in foodGroup.widgets
         output the widget div
```